# Update command on AccessDataSource doesn't update table as expected

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, data-binding, accessdatasource

Update button executes the query, but nothing shows up in my database. Any thoughts as to why?

I've moved it in and out of an `UpdatePanel`. I've tried with the couple of variations on the variables like `@Atty_ID` or `?`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

When I click the Update button, nothing happens except the page refreshes sometimes.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel19" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="ChamberLogoDataSource" runat="server" 
                          DataFile="~/App_Data/Attorneys.mdb" 
                          SelectCommand="SELECT ATTORNEYS.CHAMBER FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ATTY_ID = ?"
                          UpdateCommand="UPDATE ATTORNEYS SET CHAMBER = ? WHERE ATTY_ID = ?">
                          <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ATT_ID" QueryStringField="ATT_ID" />
                          </SelectParameters>
                          <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CHAMBER" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ATTY_ID" />                            
                          </UpdateParameters>
                        </asp:AccessDataSource>
                        Add a Chambers logo:<br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateChambersLogoButton" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateLogo" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
Protected Sub UpdateLogo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ChamberLogoDataSource.Update()
End Sub
```

Comment: What you see is everything related to the textbox...

Comment: I see where you are going with this. Hmmm... I just tried putting the AccessDataSource inside my update panel, but that didn't make a difference either. see update question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your update parameter binding out of order, and that could be causing the update to fail because there are no matches to the WHERE clause.

Reverse the order of the UpdateParameters like below and try it.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="ChamberLogoDataSource" runat="server" 
                  DataFile="~/App_Data/Attorneys.mdb" 
                  SelectCommand="SELECT ATTORNEYS.CHAMBER FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ATTY_ID = ?"
                  UpdateCommand="UPDATE ATTORNEYS SET CHAMBER = ? WHERE (ATTY_ID = ?)">
                  <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ATT_ID" QueryStringField="ATT_ID" />
                  </SelectParameters>
                  <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CHAMBER" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ATTY_ID" />
                  </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:AccessDataSource>
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel19" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    Add a Chambers logo:<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateChambersLogoButton" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateLogo" />
                </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Hold on while I find out why.

Comment: +1, because the issue is related to order of parameters.

Comment: I took out the update panel and the page refreshes every time now, which I guess makes sense and is the reason why you use update panels, but it still doesn't update the record.